# Умные указатели C++ - утечки памяти

Tags: c++, деструктор, unique-ptr, shared-ptr

Пытаюсь реализовать класс умных указателей, но никак не могу написать деструкторы так, чтобы не было утечек памяти, Valgrind ругается. SharedPtr - это упрощенный аналог класса умного указателя с разделяемым владением, а WeakPtr - аналог std::weak_ptr. Идея состоит в том, чтобы хранить не только сам указатель, но и количество сильных/слабых ссылок. Если количество сильных ссылок стало 0, то объект удаляется.
Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class WeakPtr;

template <class T>
class SharedPtr {
    friend class WeakPtr<T>;

private:
    T* ptr_;
    std::size_t* count_;
    std::size_t* soft_links_count_;

public:
    SharedPtr() : ptr_(nullptr), count_(nullptr), soft_links_count_(nullptr) {
    }

    SharedPtr(const SharedPtr& another)
        : ptr_(another.ptr_), count_(another.count_), soft_links_count_(another.soft_links_count_) {
        if (count_)
            ++*count_;
    }

    SharedPtr(SharedPtr&& another)
        : ptr_(std::move(another.ptr_)), count_(another.count_), soft_links_count_(another.soft_links_count_) {
        another.ptr_ = nullptr;
        another.count_ = nullptr;
        another.soft_links_count_ = nullptr;
    }

    constexpr SharedPtr(std::nullptr_t) : ptr_(nullptr), count_(nullptr), soft_links_count_(nullptr) {
    }

    explicit SharedPtr(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr), count_(new std::size_t(1)), soft_links_count_(new std::size_t(0)) {
    }

    explicit SharedPtr(const WeakPtr<T>& weak)
        : ptr_(weak.ptr_), count_(weak.count_), soft_links_count_(weak.soft_links_count_) {
        if (count_) {
            ++*count_;
        }
    }

    void Swap(SharedPtr& another) {
        std::swap(ptr_, another.ptr_);
        std::swap(count_, another.count_);
        std::swap(soft_links_count_, another.soft_links_count_);
    }

    SharedPtr& operator=(const SharedPtr& another) {
        SharedPtr(another).Swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    SharedPtr& operator=(SharedPtr&& another) {
        SharedPtr(std::move(another)).Swap(*this);
        another.ptr_ = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~SharedPtr() {
        if (count_) {
            --*count_;
            if (!*count_) {
                delete soft_links_count_;
                delete count_;
                delete ptr_;
            }
        } else {
            delete soft_links_count_;
            delete ptr_;
        }
    }

    std::size_t UseCount() const {
        return count_ ? *count_ : 0;
    }

    bool Expired() const {
        return !count_ || *count_ == 0;
    }

    T* Get() const {
        return ptr_;
    }

    T* operator->() const {
        return ptr_;
    }

    T& operator*() const {
        return *ptr_;
    }

    void Reset() {
        SharedPtr<T>().Swap(*this);
    }

    template <class U>
    void Reset(U* ptr) {
        SharedPtr<T>(ptr).Swap(*this);
    }
};

template <typename T>
class WeakPtr {
    friend class SharedPtr<T>;

private:
    T* ptr_;
    std::size_t* count_;
    std::size_t* soft_links_count_;

public:
    WeakPtr(const SharedPtr<T>& shared)
        : ptr_(shared.ptr_), count_(shared.count_), soft_links_count_(new std::size_t(1)) {
    }

    WeakPtr(const WeakPtr& another)
        : ptr_(another.ptr_), count_(another.count_), soft_links_count_(another.soft_links_count_) {
        if (soft_links_count_)
            ++*soft_links_count_;
    }

    WeakPtr(WeakPtr&& another)
        : ptr_(another.ptr_), count_(another.count_), soft_links_count_(another.soft_links_count_) {
        if (soft_links_count_)
            ++*soft_links_count_;
    }

    WeakPtr() : ptr_(nullptr), count_(nullptr), soft_links_count_(nullptr) {
    }

    void Swap(WeakPtr& another) {
        std::swap(ptr_, another.ptr_);
        std::swap(count_, another.count_);
        std::swap(soft_links_count_, another.soft_links_count_);
    }

    WeakPtr& operator=(const WeakPtr& another) {
        WeakPtr<T>(another).Swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    WeakPtr& operator=(WeakPtr&& another) {
        WeakPtr<T>(std::move(another)).Swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    WeakPtr& operator=(const SharedPtr<T>& another) {
        count_ = another.count_;
        ptr_ = another.ptr_;
        if (soft_links_count_)
            --*soft_links_count_;
        soft_links_count_ = another.soft_links_count_;
        if (soft_links_count_)
            ++*soft_links_count_;
        return *this;
    }

    ~WeakPtr() {
        if (soft_links_count_) {
            --*soft_links_count_;
            if (!*soft_links_count_) {
                delete count_;
            }
        } else {
            delete count_;
        }
    }
    std::size_t UseCount() const {
        return count_ ? *count_ : 0;
    }

    bool Expired() const {
        return !count_ || *count_ == 0;
    }

    SharedPtr<T> Lock() const {
        return Expired() ? SharedPtr<T>() : SharedPtr<T>(*this);
    }

    void Reset() {
        WeakPtr<T>().Swap(*this);
    }
};
```

Все методы аналогичны етодам из стандартной библиотеки в упрощенном виде. Проблема состоит в том, что при проверки Valgrind выявляются утечки памяти. Предполагаю, что дело в деструкторах. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала написать _минимальный_ тест, воспроизводящий проблему. Используйте как можно меньше количество классов. Например, попробуйте обойтись без WeakPtr.

Comment: Очень неудобно хранить два счетчика в отдельных кусках памяти. Запутаетесь ведь.

Comment: посмотрел SharedPtr. move для обычного указателя не имеет смысла. Можно просто присвоить. А также как то очень странно реализованы операторы присваивания и перемещения.